# Div height responsivness issue?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs `.fac` and `.sub`, I want `.fac` to be on the right side and stay responsive too at the same time but .fac height doesn't stay responsive. here is the CSS

```
.sub{
width:50%;
padding:5%;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(57, 90, 142, 0.50);
}

.fac{
width:30%;
float:right;
height:relative; // tried relative and if put any % or px number it doesnt work either
padding:3% 3% 3% 7.2%;  
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(72, 112, 166, 0.25);   
}
```

if .sub text increases the footer moves with and stay responsive but thats not the case with the .fac it crosses the footer and which looks bad.
how this problem can be solved ?
Help !

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: @AlexanderScholz what do you mean by fiddle ?

Comment: create a example at: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: something like that i am facing http://jsfiddle.net/b5CLm/

Comment: `relative` is not a valid value for `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `display:table` property. Here you have an example:

use another div, put both .sub and .fac in that

```
.text_box {
            display: table-row;
            width: 100%;  
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
           }
.sub{
     position: relative;
     width:50%;
     display:table-cell;
     float:left;
     height: 100%;
    }

.fac{
     position: relative;
 width:50%;
 float:right;
 background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(72, 112, 166, 0.25);
     display:table-cell;
     height: 100%;
    }
```

[I forked your fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/N8528/1/)

Comment: if use `display: table-column` for only .fac it leaves the space between .sub and footer if i use it for both .sub text disappear ?
here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xuM3DOnROT

Comment: Can you uploaded the link example from jsfiddle? I can't access :S

Comment: k here it is http://jsfiddle.net/rana_muhammad_waqas/N8528/ if you can see that ?

Comment: I found the error. I forgot to create another div between .text and .sub/.fact. Now you can see it. It works well. [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8528/1/)
PD: Look that I added some properties to the css. It's necessary that you put `height:100%;` to all containers.